Having pointerEvent in onClick whereas using custom params in gsap, Draggable plugin
Sorry if you found an grammatically mistake in my note. English isn't my tongue language.
I'm learning GSAP and now I'm in Draggable plugin. as you know if you use onClick, by Default it will pass a pointerEvent to your function:

gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable);


Draggable.create('.some-class', {
  onClick: (pointerEvent)=>{
    console.log(pointerEvent)
  }
});

But when I use onClickParams, I'll see the pointerEvent has gone! my question is how to have onClickParams and pointerEvent at the same time:

gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable);


Draggable.create('.some-class', {
  onClick: (param1, pointerEvent)=>{
    console.log(param1); // 'param1'
    console.log(pointerEvent); // undefined
  },
  onClickParams: ['param1']
});

Thanks For Your help!

First, you should use an anonymous function instead of an arrow function, that way "this" will refer to the Draggable instance.
You can then access the last pointer event that affected the Draggable instance with "this.pointerEvent": https://gsap.com/docs/v3/Plugins/Draggable/pointerEvent/
Draggable.create('.some-class', {
  onClickParams: ['param'],
  onClick: function(param) {
    console.log(param);
    console.log(this.pointerEvent);
  },
});

